# Merge [jet-ef-provider] and [access-ef-provider]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Microsoft Access only has a single entity-framework provider, found [here](https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider). However, there are two tags about it: [jet-ef-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jet-ef-provider) and [access-ef-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-ef-provider)

Moreover, the GitHub page by the developer states:

> For question on how to use it please use stackoverflow, tags access-ef-provider and jet-ef-provider.

This seems silly to me. I'd like one to be marked as a synonym of the other. I'd prefer the main tag to be [jet-ef-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jet-ef-provider), since that's closest to the name of the provider

Comment: Are you sure that is correct?   There were two distinct dbase engines, Jet was the old and buggy one but still commonly used.  It was replaced by Ace in 2007, a complete rewrite.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I know Jet isn't Ace, but this is a separate, non-Microsoft EF provider. Why the author decided to name it jet-ef-provider while it supports accdb files (jet doesn't support those) is a mystery to me (perhaps he switched from jet to ace at some point, but I haven't analyzed his source code).

Comment: Okay, I agree.  Please also consider a tag wiki edit.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the suggestion. I've put a suggestion for a [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20267163) and a modified [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3808949) into the review queue

Comment: 9 of the questions had both the tags on them. linked em up.